# Computing the 3D Transformation between Two Sets of Points

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Using a Microsoft Kinect, I am collecting depth data about an object. From these data, I create a "cloud" of points (point cloud), which, when plotted, allow me to view the object that I scanned using the Kinect.

However, I would like to be able to collect multiple point clouds from different "views" and align them. More specifically, I would like to use an algorithm such as [Iterative Closest Point (ICP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) to do so, transforming each point in my point cloud by calculating the rotation and translation between each cloud that I collect and the previously-collected cloud.

However, while I understand the process behind ICP, I do not understand how I would implement it in 3D. Perhaps it is my lack of mathematical experience or my lack of experience with frameworks such as OpenCV, but I cannot find a solution. I would like to avoid libraries such as the Point Cloud Library which does this sort of thing for me, since I would like to do it myself.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated (if there is a solution that involves OpenCV/python that I can work on, that would be even better!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am currently struggling with ICP myself. Here is what I have gathered so far:

ICP consists of three steps:

- Given two point clouds A and B, find pairs of points between A and B that *probably* represent the same point in space. Often this is done simply by matching each point with its closest neighbor in the other cloud, but you can use additional features such as color, texture or surface normal to improve the matching. Optionally you can then discard the worst matches.
- Given this list of correspondence pairs, find the optimal transformation from A to B
- Apply this transformation to all points in A
- repeat these three steps until you converge on an acceptable solution.

Step one is easy, although there are lots of ways to optimize its speed, since this is the major performance bottleneck of ICP; and to improve the accuracy, since this is the main source of errors. OpenCV can help you there with the [FLANN library](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html).

I assume your troubles are with step two, finding the best transformation given a list of correspondences.

One common approach works with [Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Here is a rough sketch of the algorithm. Searching for ICP & SVD will give a lot of further references.

- Take the list of corresponding points A<sub>1</sub>..A<sub>n</sub> and B<sub>1</sub>..B<sub>n</sub> from step 1
- calculate the centroid C<sub>a</sub> of all points in A and the centroid C<sub>b</sub> of all points in B
- Calculate the 3x3 covariance matrix M
  M = (A<sub>1</sub> - C<sub>a</sub>)* (B<sub>1</sub> - C<sub>b</sub>)<sup>T</sup> + ... + (A<sub>n</sub> - C<sub>a</sub>)* (B<sub>n</sub> - C<sub>b</sub>)<sup>T</sup>
- Use SVD to calculate the 3x3 Matrices U and V for M
  *(OpenCV has a [function to perform SVD](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#SVD))*
- Calculate R = U * V<sup>T</sup>.
  This is your desired optimal rotation matrix.
- Calculate the optimal translation as C<sub>b</sub> - R*C<sub>a</sub>
- The optimal transformation is the combination of R and this translation

Please note that I have not yet implemented this algorithm myself, so I am only paraphrasing what I read.

Comment: I appreciate that you have shared your findings with me - perhaps I can implement this approach soon and inform you of the result

Comment: I will indeed attempt to implement this approach into my project following the holidays. I sincerely thank you for you insight.

Comment: Notice that it should be R = V * U^T

Comment: you should perform some outlier filtering of your found correspondence to improve convergence. E.g. the approach in the [trimmed-ICP](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.2020&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is good for partial overlapping point clouds. [libpointmatcher](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher) is a pretty good opensource c++ implementation maybe you check out the source good for some ideas

Answer (score 4):

A very good introduction to ICP, including accelerated variants, can be found in Rusinkievicz's old paper [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~smr/papers/fasticp/fasticp_paper.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

A new ICP algorithm is now in OpenCV contrib (surface matching module). It also benefits from the variants of various types (including Rusinkievicz and more):

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/surface_matching/doc/surface_matching.html

For MATLAB implementation:
http://www.mathworks.co.jp/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47152-icp-registration-using-efficient-variants-and-multi-resolution-scheme/content/icp_mod_point_plane_pyr.m

Comment: I tried your matlab implementation of the ICP method. I have a few questions:
1- Is there any limitation on the number of points for the source and the mapped points? Should the number of points be the same?
2- I noticed that the algorithm needs a mesh for the point cloud. This becomes a challenge when the number of points is not that many and the cluster has concave features. What mesh generator would you recommend for a point cloud with concave features?

Comment: 1. By nature, no equality on the number of points is expected.
2. No mesh is expected. This would be unnecessary.

Comment: I ran out of space so I had to continue our conversation in the below.

Comment: First link (opencv's) is broken

Answer (score 0):

@tdirdal:

Ok then I may not be looking at the correct code.
I am talking about this package [link](http://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47152-icp-registration-using-efficient-variants-and-multi-resolution-scheme/content/icp_mod_point_plane_pyr.m):
The code starts with constructing a transformation matrix and then loads a *.ply which contains a mesh (faces and vertices). The rest of the code depends on the mesh that has been loaded.

I have a very simple problem and I would appreciate it if you could let me know how I can solve this using the ICP method. I have the following two point clouds. P2 is a subset of P39 and I would like to find P2 in P39. Please let me know how I can use your matlab package to solve this problem.

### P2:

11.2706   -5.3392    1.1903

13.6194   -4.8500    2.6222

8.8809   -3.8407    1.1903

10.7704   -2.1800    2.6222

8.5570   -1.0346    1.1903

13.1808   -2.5632    1.1903

### P39:

-1.9977 -4.1434 -1.6750

-4.3982   -3.5743   -3.1069

-6.8065   -3.0071   -1.6751

-9.2169   -2.4386   -3.1070

-11.6285   -1.8696   -1.6751

-16.4505   -0.7305   -1.6751

-14.0401   -1.3001   -3.1070

-18.8577   -0.1608   -3.1070

-25.9398   -0.8647   -3.1070

-30.1972   -4.6857   -3.1069

-28.2349   -2.5200   -3.1069

-29.5843   -0.2496   -1.6751

-31.1688   -2.0974   -3.1070

-21.2580    0.4093   -1.6751

-23.6450    0.9838   -3.1070

-26.0636    1.5073   -1.6751

-28.4357    1.9258   -3.1070

Comment: Ply is not necessarily a mesh. It can well be a point cloud. So just use the vertices of the loaded mesh, if you have a mesh. Otherwise, load only the vertices.

Comment: For this simple problem, you can do some ransac scheme to find the best alignment (just sample some random sets and try to register, you should be very unlucky if you can't get a reasonable one in 1000 iterations). However, for the real scenario, please take a look at the surface matching module I described. This exactly solves this issue.

Comment: Okay you have a fundamental mistake here. ICP only works when point clouds are initialized with some rough alignment. That means, they should in some sense overlap. ICP is only a gradient descent like optimization. You should read more about it, in the provided links.